# Improving the efficiency of a C# loop

Tags: c#, loops, pi

I am making a program that estimates pi through increasing the number of sides of a polygon with a given radius to an extremely high number, taking the area, and dividing it by the radius squared. I have the following:

```
            double radius = 5;

            for (double sides = 3;sides < 10000;sides++)
            {
                double pi_est = ((radius * radius * sides * Math.Sin((360 / sides)*(Math.PI/180))) / 2) / (radius * radius);
                richTextBox1.AppendText(pi_est+"\n");
            }
```

As of now, this takes about 5 seconds to complete. Is there anything I could re write that would improve the efficiency of my loop?

Comment: Just wondering, is this for project euler or something?

Comment: Millions (even billions) of digits of pi are available online, so it's unlikely you'd need to estimate it yourself.

Comment: @Kinected, Nah, just an exercise for myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That `AppendText` call is going to cost a lot of time because it implies accessing the UI. Accumulate the string using a `StringBuilder` or an array with `String.Join` instead.

You should never use a `double` as an iteration variable; use an `int` instead (that's less of an efficiency problem and more of a potential gotcha).

`radius*radius` cancels out -- note that `pi` is independent of the radius used, so you can just assume the radius is equal to 1 and ignore it.

All written out:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(int sides = 3; sides < 10000; sides++) {
    double pi_est = sides * Math.Sin((2*Math.PI)/sides) / 2;
    sb.append(pi_est + "\n");
}
richTextBox1.AppendText(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Wish I could give another upvote for the reminder that pi is the same no matter the radius

Answer (score 5):

For starters you could precalculate radius * radius outside the loop.

Also if not needed inside the loop update your rich text box *once* outside the loop and just use a StringBuilder inside.

Comment: Compiler ought to figure out that one.

Comment: Amusingly, `radius*radius` *cancels out*, so the better answer would be to just drop it entirely.